# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass while trying to read post on different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to list all the posts of the current_user in a view not associated with the posts controller. I tried doing it but can't seem to wrap my head around it

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @posts = Post.all

  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5, :order => 'id DESC')
end


def show
end

 def new
   @post = Post.new
  end


def edit
end


 def create

   @post = Post.new(post_params) 
  @post.email = current_user.username
  respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end


 def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  #protect_from_forgery with: :null_session #i added this from SO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 helper_method :mypost

 def mypost
     @mypost = Post.all

     @mypost = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5, :order => 'id DESC')

  end



protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
  end
end
```

in the view of new site

```
 <% @mypost.each do |mypost| %>
       <%= link_to post do %>
           <div id="rectmine">
        <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
       <p><%= post.author %><p>price: <%= post.price %></p> location: <%= post.school %>
      <hr style="width: 505px;">

   <% end %>

    <% if current_user.email == post.email %>
   <p>This is your post! Feel free to edit or delete it. ->  </p>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: have you added `helper :all` in ApplicationController?

Comment: I added  helper_method :mypost, check my edit

Comment: In place of using @mypost.each use mypost.each as mypost is helper method and it will return pagination post AR object. Instance variable in view should come from controller/action, filter actions, included modules or required lib class/actions.

Comment: omg!! that did it! thank you so much! I was messing with this for a good bit, wow

Comment: And there you can optimize your code in mypost helper by removing Post.all statement and removing @mypost identifier as it will keep memory occupied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the new variable from the helper.

```
helper_method :get_post_paginate

def get_post_paginate
     @mypost = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5, :order => 'id DESC')
     @mypost
end
```

And use the method call in the view

```
<% get_post_paginate.each do |mypost| %>
```

Comment: still getting the same error `NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#edit` and `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: try initializing  @mypost in the PostController

Comment: in the index method? as in @mypost = Post.all?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you place the code in the controller you are calling. For example, if you call the index action of your NoPostsController you can place the code within that action and it should work fine. Seems weird to me to place a query within a helper, that logic does not belong there in my opinion.

The only thing you want is that current user is accessible in every controller.

Comment: I want post to be accessible from a foreign view in the devise edit user view, in there i want to list that particular user's post but first i'd like just to get the posts on that page